# How can I create a divided circle into 4 sections in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a divided circle into 4 sections and put some SVG in each section? as below.

[image]

I tried a lot but I could not be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

This type of custom of UI is possible using a `CustomPaint` widget with `CustomPainter` in flutter.

It gives you a canvas to draw any complex UI using elemental shapes like circles, arc, lines, path, etc.

CustomPaint Widget:

```
CustomPaint(
   painter: ChartPainter(),
   child: Container(),
 )
```

ChartPainter Widget:

```
class ChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
     // TODO: start painting shapes here
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You can check the official documentation for CustomPaint widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

I have added a small project to get you started:
[QuadrantChart](https://github.com/yusufpats/quadrant_chart)